# Riemann stieltjes integral : Show that $\int_{a}^{b} fdg=0$ if only if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Question: Let $f$ be continuous and such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in  [a,b]$. If $g$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. Show that $\int_{a}^{b} fdg=0$ if only if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

I thought I could solve the problem using the Mean-Value Theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. We know that $ f,g$ are functions on $[a,b] $ with $ f$ continuous and $ g $ increasing. And let $m$ and $M$ be respectively the inf
and sup of $f$ on $ [a, b]$. Then there exists $c \in [m, M] $ such that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dg(x) = c(g(b)-g(a)).$$

So, suppose that $\int_{a}^{b} fdg=0$, therefore $c(g(b)-g(a))=0$. Then $c = 0$ or $(g(b)-g(a))=0$, but the second one can´t happen because $ g $ is an increasing function. Therefore, $c=0$.

Also, we know that $f$ is continuous, therefore $c = f(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$. In particular, $c=0=f(x) $ for some $x \in [a,b]$.

Is this a valid proof? Is there an other way to prove it?

Comment: Hi jim. What have you tried, what are your thoughts about it? At the moment your post shows no evidence of effort. You can click "Edit" above, to improve your post. You should also review the following, since you are new here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: @plop You misread the question.

Comment: @jimyo, still mulling it over but the question asks you to conclude "for all" and you have written "for some," which at first glance would not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to do that direction is by contrapositive. That is, assume there exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)>0$. By continuity of $f$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $f(y)>\varepsilon>0$ on some neighborhood $B_\delta(x)\cap [a,b]$. For simplicity assume $B_\delta(x) \subseteq [a,b]$. Since $f$ is non-negative,

$$
\int_a^b f(x) dg \geq \int_{B_\delta(x)} \varepsilon dg = \varepsilon (g(x+\delta) - g(x-\delta)).
$$

The last quantity is positive since $g$ is increasing.